# A new Pharo version was launched. What do I do with my old images?

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, pharo, change-tracking, monticello

I noticed Pharo 9 [was released](https://pharo.org/news/pharo9-released.html)  past month (july 2021). I have several Pharo 8 images with packages and classes I created while learning programming in Pharo. Is it possible to just update the old image to the new version, or the standard way is to just File Out / File In, or use a change tracking tool like Iceberg to migrate my packages between images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common practice is to start every day with a fresh image, where you load (using Metacello and Iceberg) your code. Best practice adds CI/CD to that, so your tests are run every day against the latest stable version and the development image of Pharo 10, and on every commit of your code.

So add some git repos and commit your code from your old images there, so you can load them in new images